# BCM_SETSHIELD does not work

Tags: mfc, windows-vista, uac

I am using MFC with VS2005 and I want to add the shield icon to a button. I created a control member variable for the button and in InitDialog I have

```
// BCM_SETSHIELD
this->m_ctrlStartact.SendMessage(0x1600+0x000C, 0, TRUE);
this->m_ctrlStartact.SetButtonStyle(BS_FLAT);
```

However, the shield does not appear. According to the Manifest, I have the correct version of the commctrl:

```
    <assemblyIdentity 
        type="win32" 
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
        version="6.0.0.0" 
        processorArchitecture="X86" 
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
        language="*" 
    />
```

What can be the remaining problem?

Comment: Have you tried to switch lines? What happens if you call SendMessage before SetButtonStyle? Also, I have seen somewhere that lParam in the SendMessage is set to 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: Does not work unfortunately :( In fact, I don't think that SetButtonStyle is required/correct for the "WinAPI-way" anyway (I read somewhere that FlatSyle=System makes the button use the "system" (=Winapi?) way rather than the Windows.Forms). There must be something essential missing here :(

Comment: Just tried it in a very simple application. "this->m_ctrlStartact.SendMessage(0x1600+0x000C, 0, TRUE);" works for me if I do it in OnInitDialog. Check if the m_ctrlStartact member is actually valid at the time you do the SendMessage.

Comment: Michael, thanks too for assistance. Yes, m_ctrlStartact is definitely correct (e.g. EnableWindow(FALSE) works). Which MFC and which VS version are you using? To what _WIN32_WINNT,_WIN32_IE etc. set? If you have >VS.2005, could you think about anything which is needed to get it work?

Comment: SOLVED!!! For some reason I had the manifest file excluded from the build. Now it works :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!! For some reason I had the manifest file excluded from the build. Now it works :) :) – divB Jul 5 at 15:07